# Log4j not working on Linux server, but working in Eclipse (Windows)

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I am currently having an issue where my Log4j is not working when I have the JAR package placed in a Linux RHEL server. I have included all the steps below and hopefully you can help me, cheers.

My program is a Maven project.

1. Log4j properties is under src/main/resources
2. My log4j is coming from an entry in my pom.xml. log4j packages are in my local Maven repo.
3. The logging works fine when I run my program on Eclipse on my laptop
4. I export the JAR package as a Runnable JAR.
5. I select "Package Required libraries into generated JAR"
6. Copy the JAR into the RHEL server.
7. Run the JAR
8. Get log4j WARN NO APPENDERS message.

And yeah I have read the wiki page but I just cant get it to work. Hopefully someone can please help me. Thanks.

Happy to provide any more information.

Comment: What is the level log that you put in your file?... When you execute your jar is it creating the file? are you getting any error?

Comment: I am trying to log to INFO level. I have the file created before I execute, and it does not write to it - I just get some text to my screening saying WARN no appenders found etc

Comment: Is the log4j config file located in the jar file? Normally during the packaging process it should be added in the jar. Can you unzip it to confirm it? If not there then it was not added during packaging.

Comment: @ngiallelis I checked the jar and yes, its under the resources folder at the top level. I have no idea why its not working.